# Windows 10 Sleep mode, turn off power, start up again

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

I have a desktop pc with windows 10 installed. I'm using sleep mode to power the pc down and have all programs active again after I power it up again. This works great, but if I shutdown the power to the pc, the pc will load from scratch, with all programs closed (and not just wakeup again). I have read about hibernation mode etc. but this option isn't really available.

I would really like to turn off the power during the night, so is there any way I can activate hibernation mode?

Comment: [Hibernate - Enable or Disable in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried enabling the hybrid mode but I fear its not possible on my system. Is it possible that depending on the system, hybrid mode cant be enabled?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

> hibernation mode etc. but this option isn't really available

Have you looked into output of `powercfg -a`?
With S3 available you can put your PC to sleep (suspend to RAM).
With S4 you can hibernate your PC (suspend to disk; longer load time, but you can pull the power cable).

If S4 is available on your PC, you can switch on hibernate mode with `powercfg -h on`. This creates the hidden/system file hiberfil.sys and you're able to hibernate your PC.